# How do I copy data from one row in a google sheet to another tab in the same sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

To expand on the surface level detail of my question; I have one google sheet tab which updates automatically with data each Monday. What I need to be able to do is copy that row from it's tab within the Google Sheet to another tab within the same over arching sheet. This copied row needs to be placed one down from the previous row (week 1 would be row 1, week 2 row 2 etc).

So far I have set up a trigger for this script to run each Monday (so I've managed the easy part...) but I still cannot figure out how to do the main body of work! I've had a look at some similar bits of code (one of which I've pasted down below) where data gets moved across to a new sheet when a box is ticked or when a certain value is noticed in a cell, but I couldn't modify either of these to work in my case.

I'm completely new to using Google Script and with no background in any language so help on this would be amazing! Or if anybody knows a way of performing this function without the need of Script that would be even better! (I've looked into using =today() and using the dates i would be looking for as triggers, but of course that comes up with an error as the text of the cell is '=today()' and not the actual date...)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Completed" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("main");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me be clear about this.  You currently have a sheet which is updated automatically.  Which in my mind means that a user did not change it.  So there are no onEdit triggers generated for that action.  Is that your understanding?

Comment: It would be nice to know how you are actually updating the data? Also a sample sheet with some examples of what you want would be helpful. Also take a look at [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), it may do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Cooper correct, no person will be updating the tab, it's done by various connectors on different tabs automatically pulling data from various sources (FaceBook Ads, Google Analytics, CRM) via API's onto their own unique tabs, the cells im interested in then get pulled into the tab that I'm currently trying to pull data out from again. Very convoluted I know!

Comment: @Raserhin The data is being updated via API's from various sources (Google Analytics, Facebook Ads, CRM) onto their own tabs, the tab that is colating this data into one row of top level metrics on a seperate tab that gets updated each monday. I then want this to get copied across to (yet another) tab but to one row down each time. I'll have a look at making a quick example sheet now and have a look into the `appendRow()` function too, thanks!

Comment: @Raserhin Here's the example Sheet, which will hopefully help! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3UdG4ybhzfepEuQkT0Wc3SWEd4BHqbY-gXvdqjzH-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cozy Have you checked if the trigger is being executed when this API fill the tabs? If it doesn't, you will need to use another strategy to append this data. Maybe a install-able time trigger managing the already inserted data.